# apache2, I can't suppress this line from apache logs

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2, httpd

I've done this and other attempts, but not working for me:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
setEnvIf Request_URI "refresh.*" dontlog
CustomLog /home/alan/logs/apache.log common env=!dontlog
...
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

this line in apache.log
obs: the numbers after the refresh.php file, it's dynamic

```
123.123.123.123 - - [25/Sep/2021:06:54:41 -0300] "GET /test1/test2/refresh.php?_=1632563669417 HTTP/2.0" 200 75 "https://abc.def.com/index.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4636.22 Safari/537.36"
```

any suggestion, guys? thanks!

Comment: Try to remove the star (`*`) from the string after `Request_URI`

Comment: resolved, `TransferLog` was active on vhost, just commented.